React Native Expo + react-native-reanimated error - window.matchMedia
When I try to run a development build using the expo run:ios command and I use a component that uses Reanimated:

"expo": "50.0.11",
"react-native": "0.73.5",
"react-native-reanimated": "3.6.2",

I receive an error:
 ERROR  TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I tried changing the reanimated versions but it didn't help. I have the impression that the error appeared suddenly because there was no problem with this version before
